# Crystal Report "Selecionar Especialista" filtrar por uma string

Tags: crystal-reports

Como devo adicionar a string 'usuario', declarada fora do Crystal Report em c#, para filtrar o relatório no Crystal Report conforme a imagem abaixo. Ou qual maneira certa de fazer isto no Crystal Report? Visual Studio Community 2017 ODBC Mysql.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Usuario seria um parâmetro ?

Comment: seria uma "string" declarada no c# eu precisava fazer um filtro com esta string dentro do Crystal Report

Comment: Passe por parâmetro e aplique no selecionar registro.

Comment: Poderia me dizer como passo uma string, declarada no c#, para parâmetro para ser utilizada dentro do Crystal Report e fazer o filtro.

Comment: Nunca trabalhei com C# , mas em qualquer linguagem que integre com o CR tem sempre a opção de passar parâmetro.No filtro de registro (relatorio/forma sel/registro) ligue ao parãmetro

Comment: passe por parâmetro ...select nome from usuario where codigo_usuario = 1 <= (parâmetro) where codigo_usuario = %jose% <= (parâmetro)